# If I remove link from li it stops expand

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help.
If I remove the `href` from an `<a>` element or if I change the `href` to `#` then the expand stops working,

```
<li class="dropdown level0"> 
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://localhost/dev/index.php?  main_page=index&amp;cPath=1">HardwareCENAS</a><span class="headerCollapsible collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#catHead_1"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu collapse" id="catHead_1">
        <li class="level1">
            <a href="http://localhost/dev/index.php?  main_page=index&amp;cPath=1_17">CDROM Drives</a>
        </li>
        <li class="level1">
            <a href="http://localhost/dev/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=1_4">Graphics Cards</a>
        </li>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? The problem is when the width of the device is small enough to trigger the collapsable menu, the span (which is a small + sign) works, but if I remove the link from the href (because I want to expand the sub menu but not reload the page) it does not expand anymore.

Can someone help?

Comment: if you do this `<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">HardwareCENAS</a>` it stops working?

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing a search in the CSS for "dropdown-toggle" and see what link-specific elements it is setting. You can then change the CSS to apply the link-specific elements to the whole "dropdown-toggle" class rather than just to links.

Comment: Better yet, load the page into Chrome, do an Inspect Element, and see what styles are being applied.